# Выборка данных с БД при условии

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток господа. Прошу вашей помощи, так как не могу разобраться как реализовать одну фичу.

Имеется таблица в БД в которой есть 4 столбца:

```
| id | Name | Status | Quantity |
+----+------+--------+----------+
```

Через PHP я добавляю в БД данные скажем о фруктах, их состоянии и количестве.

В идеале должно получаться так:

```
| id | Name | Status | Quantity |
+----+------+--------+----------+
|  1 | Appl |  Good  |    10    |
|  2 | Appl |  Bad   |    4     |
|  3 | Appl |  Mell  |    42    |
|  4 | Pear |  Good  |    11    |
|  5 | Pear |  Mell  |    15    |
|  6 | Pear |  Bad   |    2     |
......
```

И список таких фруктов около 10,000. Время от времени я добавляю в таблицу не достающие фрукты, так как НЕТ возможности сделать `Unique` столбец, я перед добавлением делаю проверку через PHP с запросами в БД, если такой фрукт есть - то не добавлять, если нету - то добавить.

Но в один прекрасный день, что-то пошло не так и моя проверка не сработала, в итоге в БД появились задублированные данные к примеру:

```
| id | Name | Status | Quantity |
+----+------+--------+----------+
|  1 | Appl |  Good  |    10    |
|  2 | Appl |  Bad   |    4     |
|  3 | Appl |  Mell  |    42    |
| 141| Appl |  Good  |    10    |
| 142| Appl |  Bad   |    4     |
| 143| Appl |  Mell  |    42    |
......
```

Теперь соответственно есть 2 варианта развития событий:

1. Написать запрос в БД который будет находить повторяющиеся строки по `Name` и `Status` и удалять строки с наименьшим `ID`. Т.е. находит 2 строки `|2|Appl|Bad|4|` и `|142|Appl|Bad|4|`, у второй строки `ID` больше, значит удалить первую строку.
2. Написать запрос, который через PHP будет вытягивать с БД значения с наибольшим ID.

Прошу подсказать как можно написать одно из вышеприведенных условий, либо натолкните на правильную мысль. Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: 3 вариант - сделать отдельную таблицу, массив со списокм уникальных данных, будут 3 запроса, вначале в первую таблицу, есть ли такой продукт, если есть, добавляем в основновную, если нет, дополнительно дублируем во вспомогательную. Дубликаты удалить проходом в цикле по всем.

Comment: Кстати, вы в поиске на сайте не пробовали искать "удаление дублей", https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9  первый же ответ даже про яблоки. И что самое странное, структура и данные как у вас и текст примерно такой же про "что то пошло не так"

Comment: @Mike хм, видимо примеры на яблоках нынче популярны. Я почитаю, спасибо

Comment: Популярность яблок тут не причём, это преподы ленятся задание заново сформулировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалите дубликаты и создайте уникальный индекс по двум полям:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Table_Name_Status_uindex ON table (Name, Status);
```

При инсерте обрабатывайте исключение.

Comment: таблица забита уже данными который повторяются по полям (Name, Status) по этому ваш запрос на выставление индекса не сработает

Comment: @madfan41k для этого я и написал что дубли нужно удалить.

Comment: @madfan41k Вообще это MySQL и если создать уникальный индекс как `ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX myindex (Name, Status);` то индекс будет создан и при этом дубли удалены автоматически

Comment: @Mike я такого не знал, спасибо, учту

Comment: Как я могу создать уникальный индекс если у Яблока несколько состояний? Если будет уникальный индекс, тогда в таблицу я смогу занести только одно состояние яблока а все остальные бд проигнорирует

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Вам предлагают сделать уникальный индекс из двух полей сразу. Это значит что уникальной будет именно связка Name-Status. Вот если бы вы сделали индекс только по полю Name было бы так как вы говорите

Answer (score 1):

Вот второй вариант

```
SELECT MAX(id), name status, quantity FROM `table` WHERE 1 group by name, status, qty
```